# interpretation of boxcox with lambda equal 0

Tags: data-transformation, transform, variance-stabilizing

I am working on this non linear data set, and running my Box-Cox I find that the best value to use is $\lambda = 0$.

If I understand correctly, $\lambda =2$ implies $Y^2$. Similarly, $\lambda = -0.5$ corresponds to $1 \over \sqrt Y$. However how would I work with a null lambda, all $Y$ values being made 0 makes little sense? NOT 0, 1

Any explanation would be much useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Box-Cox transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform) is defined as

$$ y^{(\lambda)} =
\begin{cases}
\frac{y^\lambda - 1}{\lambda}   & \text{if } & \lambda \ne 0, \\
\log(y) & \text{if } & \lambda=0.
\end{cases} $$

For further details check the original paper that introduced it:

> Box, G. E., & Cox, D. R. (1964). [An analysis of transformations.](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Eabe/lista/pdfQWaCMboK68.pdf)
> Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series B (Methodological),
> 211-252.

So there is really nothing to interpret, it's simply a log transformation.

---

Also notice that $x^0 = 1$, so it would rather be all ones, rather than all zeros.

Comment: Interesting is the function based on lambda continuous for all y?

Comment: @rannoudanames $\log(y)$ is continuous, $(y^\lambda-1)/\lambda$ is also continuous, so yes.

Comment: More than that is true: for positive $y$ and real $\lambda$, the function $(y, \lambda)\to y^{(\lambda)}$ is differentiable.  In particular, the natural logarithm arises as the limit of $y^{(\lambda)}$ as $\lambda \to 0$.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider   non-null $y$ values, the coefficient of variation of the Box-Cox transformation for a real $\lambda$-power near $0$ goes like:
$$ \frac{\exp \left( \lambda\ \log y\right)−y^0}{\lambda−0}≈\frac{1+\lambda\log y−1}{\lambda}$$
as $\lambda$ tends to $0$. So the limit is $\log y$. So in a way, a constant behaves like a limit behaviour of the logarithm, or the other way around.

The logarithm is somehow dimensionless, or $0$-homogenous, like a constant. A personal and physical interpretation can be found at [What is the logarithm of a kilometer? Is it a dimensionless number?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/72464/27454). In short:

- If you consider $y$ as a non-zero constant, $y^0=1$,
- If you consider $y$ as a realisation of a  continuous variable, you inherit a variational context, and the natural limit is a logarithm.